# Xamarin Forms: Custom View (Single Implementation)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

I've been searching high and low to find an example of how to write a custom UI element that has one implementation (single renderer).

For example, is there a way to simply implement a class that inherits from StackLayout (written in C#) and can then be slotted into other layouts (xaml) as a UI element (similar to how its done using xml views in Android)?

The following is what I have right now, but I am getting errors:

**ButtonCustom.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace DWalker
{
    public partial class ButtonCustom : StackLayout
    {
        public ButtonCustom()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public Color TextColor
        {
            get { return this.Text.TextColor; }
            set { this.Text.TextColor = value; }
        }

        public Label TextControl
        {
            get { return this.Text; }
            set { this.Text = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

**ButtonCustom.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StackLayout 
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:common="clr-namespace:Dwalker;assembly=DWalker"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="DWalker.ButtonCustom">

    <Image 
        x:Name="Icon" 
        Source="Icon.png" />

    <Label 
        x:Name="Text" 
        Text="Hello" 
        HorizontalOptions="Center" 
        LineBreakMode="NoWrap" 
        Font="Small" 
        TextColor="Black"/>

</StackLayout>
```

Then I'd like to add my custom element to a xaml layouts ContentPage like so:

**ViewStart.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:common="clr-namespace:DWalker;assembly=DWalker"
    xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:DWalker;assembly=DWalker"
    x:Class="DWalker.ViewStart"
    Title="DWalker" >

    <AbsoluteLayout>

        <controls:ButtonCustom />

    </AbsoluteLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: You can try inheriting from `ContentView`: 

`public partial class ButtonCustom : StackLayout`

and in CustomButton.xaml, wrap StackLayout by ContentView.

Comment: I agree with Vishnu, just put it inside a ContentView

Comment: Thanks @Vishnu I will give that a shot and report back.